# Attributes such as polygon sides lengths to be extracted

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to get polygon attributes such as lengths of its sides and area reported in QGIS?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a window"? Do you mean like when you use the Identify tool and expand the Derived attributes?

Comment: i mean like reported as little table for example.

Comment: Such as the attribute table of the layer?

Comment: I see it is possible in the Field calculator under Geometry when it comes to area at least.

Comment: Yes the field calculator has the following functions that you may find useful: `$area`, `$perimeter`

Comment: yes thanks, I got to know already about $perimeter but i need from point to point in a rectangle. If that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the "identify result panel" and then click on "derived" for that:

[image]

Comment: Solution is to install plugin called "Shape tools" . Navigate to it in Toolbox after installed. select in it "geodesic measurement layer" under "vector geometry"  and Run. then lengths are shown on polygon directly